# How to get the list with the higher sum of its elements

Tags: python

I was wondering if anyone could help me with a Python problem I have. I have four lists, each list holds floats (decimals). I'm adding all the floats that each list contains. The part I'm stuck on is I want to know which of the four list has a higher sum. I know I could use if statements but does anyone know a more of a efficient way. For instance:

```
foodmart = [12.33,5.55]
nike = [42.20,69.99]
gas_station = [0.89,45.22]
toy_store = [10.99,15.32]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Represent the lists as a `dict` and use `max` with an optional `key` function to calculate the `sum`

Instead of representing the lists in the way you did, use a dictionary. It would be easier to determine the correct shop and work on any number of lists / shops without the need to enumerate them in the max routine. This would be more Pythonic and maintainable

```
>>> shops = dict()
>>> shops['foodmart'] = [12.33,5.55]
>>> shops['nike'] = [42.20,69.99]
>>> shops['gas_station'] = [0.89,45.22]
>>> shops['toy_store'] = [10.99,15.32]
>>> max(shops, key = lambda k:sum(shops[k]))
'nike'
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I never used dictionary before, so how do I define shop because I'm getting a error

Comment: @AustinSmith start with `shop={}`.

Comment: @AustinSmith: Yes, its possible and easy enough but would be difficult to state in the comment section. I would suggest you to frame a new question for this problem

Comment: @AustinSmith Better ask this as a new question.

Comment: @AustinSmith: `[(k , sum(v)) for k, v in shops.items()]`

Comment: oh ok and that just sums up everything in the nike since thats the max of the store, but what is items() is it like values().

Comment: @AustinSmith: [dict.items()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items), returns a copy of the dictionary's key and value as a list of tuples. In Python 3.X it returns an iterator of key - value pair

Answer (score 7):

use `max()`:

```
>>> max(foodmart,nike,gas_station,toy_store, key=sum)
>>> [42.2, 69.99]
```

`help()` on `max`:

> max(iterable[, key=func]) -> value
>
> max(a, b, c, ...[, key=func]) ->
> value
>
> With a single iterable argument, return its largest item. With two or
> more arguments, return the largest argument.

Comment: hi what is In[80] and Out[80] do specifically need those

Comment: @AustinSmith That's from `IPython` console. instead of `>>>` used in normal interpreter IPython used [In],[Out].

Comment: @AustinSmith see Abhijit's answer, you need to create a dictionary first to get the name here.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: I've started using ipython in `ipython --classic` mode sometimes when I want to post for a beginner and I don't want to distract from the point.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> max([1,2],[3,4],[2,3], key=lambda x: sum(x))
[3, 4]
```

Comment: could you explain where the numbers come from, what lambda is and the last part [3,4], mainly the whole thing sorry new to Python since a month ago

Comment: @CRUSADER -- Of course.  However, the spirit of SO is that comments are "noise", while the answers are what is actually important.  In this case, your answer would be better without the `lambda` as you wouldn't be creating a pointless function that the user needs to decipher before figuring out what the whole line does.  `lambda` is *extremely useful*, but there's no reason to use it here as it just makes the code more confusing.